# ROS Communication Protocol

Tags: ros, communication, xml, master, subscribe

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
Is there a complete documentation for the ROS communication protocol anywhere?
(especially explaining the buildup of the XMLrpc messages)

I want to write a very slim ROS independent node in C for it, which does not use any ROS library.

Do I need XML for the Master or is there another simpler possibility of publishing or subscribing topics?

Regards,

Cyborg-X1

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42907/ros-communication-protocol/) by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1376 on 2012-09-03

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess the [conceptual overview wiki page](http://ros.org/wiki/ROS/Concepts) is a good starting point. The [master xmlrpc API](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Master_API) and [slave xmlrpc API](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Slave_API) and [parameter xmlrpc API](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Parameter%20Server%20API) pages should provide a hopefully complete list of xmlrpc functions that are implemented by the core and that must be implemented (slave api) by a node.

For setting up subscriptions and publications and accessing parameters, xmlrpc will be required. The actual communication on the topics then uses a different binary format. Have a look at the [msg wiki page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/msg) for at least some information. For a really generic implementation of ros in C, you will have to implement a message generator that translates msg files to c files that contain code for serializing and deserializing that message. The serialized message format is actually pretty simple. Best if you have a look at the generated files for C++ or Python to find out more information.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2012-09-03**:
Is there a documentation for the direct XML format like below (captured by wireshark):

1
Unregistered [/listener] as provider of [/rosout]
1...

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-09-03**:
Well, that's just normal xmlrpc. Google shows [this](http://xmlrpc.scripting.com/spec.html) as first hit.

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2012-09-03**:
Oh, ok, thought that is done by ros, because somewhere in the text it says it was "heavily" changed.